# Am I a better asker or answerer?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, statistics

I was wondering if there was a fairly easy way to see what percentage of my reputation comes from asking questions or answering them.

It should be fairly simple to calculate the average reputation points per question/answer.

No real reason for this I'm just a curious guy who is interested in meeting some nice pretty data.

Comment: Looks like it's easy for you. You do not have that many answers/questions. Just count.

Comment: Well yeah...but where's the fun/scalability in that :)

Comment: You could get the SO data dumps and do it yourself if your so curious..

Answer (score 2):

Ask again later

Comment: Concentrate and ask again

Comment: All signs post to maybe

Comment: Outlook not so good.

Comment: Thunderbird better?

Answer (score 1):

See this (it might take a while to load):
http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/default.aspx?qid=572

Answer (score 0):

No of answers and No of Questions in user's profile tell the whole story :)

But some stats on profile are also acceptble ;)

Comment: # of answers/questions just tells me whether I'm a more prolific asker/answerer not whether I'm any good at either :)